# How to have the same name for VCL and FMX components?

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey, vcl

Delphi manages to have `TLabel` exist in **FMX** and **VCL**.  So, how do I create two components, both with the same name, except one is for **VCL** and one is for **FMX**?

Yes, I know I can use `ifdef`s and recompile the library every time.  But that is not exactly clean code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement your two components in different [Unit Scopes](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names), which were created for this exact purpose.

For example, implement `TMyComponent` for VCL in `Vcl.MyUnit.pas`, and implement `TMyComponent` for FMX in `FMX.MyUnit.pas`.

Then, to use `TMyComponent` in any other unit, you can either:

- use `{$IFDEF}`s to conditionally specify `Vcl.MyUnit` or `FMX.MyUnit` in the `uses` clause.
- create separate projects for VCL and FMX, where the VCL project specifies `Vcl` in its [Unit Scope Names compiler setting](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler), and the FMX project specifies `FMX`, and then you can use just `MyUnit` in the `uses` clause.

Also see [Adding Unit Scope Names for Your Own Components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Adding_Unit_Scope_Names_for_Your_Own_Components).

For reference, VCL's `TLabel` is in the `Vcl.StdCtrls` unit scope, and FMX's `TLabel` is in the `FMX.StdCtrls` unit scope.

Comment: I had figured out yesterday that the key was to use namespaces.  But this is the right answer

Comment: @RohitGupta Namespaces and Unit Scopes are similar but used for slightly different purposes.